# Cypress - Error: Cannot find module '../../webpack.config.js'

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, alias, cypress

When I try to run cypress, i get the error once the window opens "Error: Cannot find module '../../webpack.config.js'"

In my plugins>index.js, i have this in module.exports `webpackOptions: require('../../webpack.config.js')`. if i change it to my whole path, its works though.

whole path: Users/username/projects/projA/tests/productA/cypress/webpack.config.js'

in my cypress>tsconfig.json, i have this:

```
  "paths": {
    "@app": [
      "./"
    ]
  }
```

in my cypress>webpack.config.js, i have this:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".d.ts", ".json"],
    alias: {
      '@app': path.resolve(__dirname, "./tests/nav.com/cypress")
    }
  },
```

SO i'm not sure what's wrong, and i pretty much don't get the alias. How can I set the correct path there....

Answer (score 2):

Based on your full path, I think you need to change your `require` to `require('../webpack.config.js')`.